# MYSQL filter by count of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count

I'm beggining with MYSQL.
I have the following query:

```
SELECT answers.data. * , COUNT( answers.reports.id ) AS rcount
FROM answers.data
LEFT JOIN answers.reports ON answers.data.id = answers.reports.answer_id
WHERE answers.data.question='4'
GROUP BY answers.data.id
```

It's returning me all answers to the current question with an added column called rcount (number of reports)

I want it to return only those with less than 3 reports. I tried the following code:

```
SELECT answers.data. * , COUNT( answers.reports.id ) AS rcount
FROM answers.data
LEFT JOIN answers.reports ON answers.data.id = answers.reports.answer_id
WHERE answers.data.question='4' AND rcount < '3'
GROUP BY answers.data.id
```

but aprrently that's not where the new condition goes. I can't find in the manual a solution since I'm new to this.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT answers.data.* , COUNT( answers.reports.id ) AS rcount
FROM answers.data
LEFT JOIN answers.reports ON answers.data.id = answers.reports.answer_id
WHERE answers.data.question='4'
GROUP BY answers.data.id
HAVING COUNT( answers.reports.id ) < 3
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Comming from other programming areas I'm not used to the syntax at all. I figured everything else by myself (and the manual) but was lost on this one. Thanks

Comment: Fashion trends come and go. Classic stays for ever.